# Connection to Azure SQL Database using Public IP and not my Azure VPN Client-assigned IP

Tags: azure-networking

I have configured a VNet in Azure with default 10.0.0.0/16 ip range.

I configured my Azure SQL Database to allow connections from the VNet.

I now want to connect my local dev pc to the VNet, so I added a Gateway to the VNet, with the default subnet 10.0.1.0/24, and then configured a Point-to-Site connection on the gateway with address pool 10.2.0.0/16.

(The above settings may be very wrong(?) - I don't know a LOT about networking, so just went with defaults where available, so am open to guidelines about how to do the above better)

I downloaded the VPN Client settings, and configured my Azure VPN Client, which connects to the Gateway and gets an IP address of 10.2.0.2.

I then tried to connect to the Azure SQL Database (using Microsoft SQL Server Mngt Studio) , and I get the popup that says my IP Address is not allowed to connect.  However, the IP Address that it is showing is my Router's static IP address with which my router is connected to the internet.

How do I get this connection in SSMS to connect using the 10.2.0.2 address that my Azure VPN client is connected with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably trying to connect to the instance using a DNS name which resolves to the public IP address of the server.

You need to setup PrivateLink for your SQL server, including configuring the DNS portion so that the DNS name you use resolves to the server’s private IP address.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/private-endpoint-overview?view=azuresql#connecting-from-an-on-premises-environment-over-vpn

> **Connecting from an on-premises environment over VPN**
>
> To establish connectivity from an on-premises environment to the database in SQL
> Database, choose and implement one of the options:
>
> [Point-to-Site connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-rm-ps)
>
> [Site-to-Site VPN connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-create-site-to-site-rm-powershell)
>
> [ExpressRoute Circuit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-howto-linkvnet-portal-resource-manager)
>
> Consider [DNS configuration scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns#dns-configuration-scenarios) as well, as the FQDN of the service can
> resolve to the public IP address.

Or, connect using the server’s private IP address in your vNet, instead of using the DNS name.